# Issues with struct and linked lists (using malloc)

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

Let me start off saying **this isn't my code!** I was only to run this and screenshot the results.

However i do not know why this will not work for me. Please help me illuminate why the below warnings and errors occur and how to fix them it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct MB MB;

struct MB 
{
   
   int  size;
   MB *prev;
   MB *next;
 
};
int main()
{
 const int SIZE = 20;
  MB *ptr, *head;
 ptr = head = malloc(sizeof(MB));
 if(ptr==NULL)
 {
    perror("malloc ...");
    exit(0);
 }
 ptr->size = rand()%1000+100;
 ptr->prev = NULL;
 int i;
 for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
 {
     
     ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(MB));
    ptr->next->prev = ptr;
    ptr->next->size = rand() % 1000+100;
    ptr=ptr->next;
 }
 ptr->next=NULL;

 ptr=head;  
 printf("Initial Free Mem Block List \n");
 printf("*****************************\n");
 printf("Head pointer --> [%8x]\n", head);
 for (i=0; i<=SIZE; i++)
 {
     printf("[%08x]\tSize=%d\t Next-->[%08x]  Prev-->[%08x]\n", ptr, ptr->size, ptr->next, ptr->prev);
     ptr=ptr->next;
 }
 printf("*****************************\n");
 printf("brk pointer --> [%8x]\n", brk(0));
}
```

Comment: This code works compiling it with gcc.

Comment: `%p` to print pointers. Add `#include <unistd.h>` for `brk`. Add `return 0` at the end of  the function. Add `void` to `main`: `int main(void)`

Comment: I've only tried it with ; sublime, Xcode, and visual studio. I will try it with gcc.

Comment: so it does work with gcc, thanks for that.

Comment: I do want to try it your way as well Kaylum, i have addded the %p which solved all the pointers issues and the unistd.h and the other suggestions but it still persists to tell me "Called object type 'struct MB' is not a function or function pointer.

Comment: Doesn't it actually say "Called object type 'struct MB*" (notice the asterisk)?

Comment: you are correct tony. but i don't understand the meaning of it or how to analyze it to say "this is what is wrong"

Comment: The asterisk means "pointer"... which in this case would mean "pointer to a struct MB".  As @kaylum said you need to change your print mask from "%x" to "%p" which is the correct mask for a pointer...    As in: `printf("Head pointer --> [%p]\n", head);`